# What determines which virtual console the graphical interface is run on?

Tags: xorg, virtual-console

I've learned that I can switch between virtual consoles by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1–F12</kbd>, and I've found that the graphical interface was usually running at either <kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> ([now on <kbd>F2</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/a/292076/349837)).

Why does this vary, and is there a way to predict it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X uses the first free virtual terminal, and the first six are now allocated for gettys by upstart from `/etc/init/tty[1-6].conf`, and traditionally by init from `/etc/inittab`.

To choose a specific virtual terminal for X, you pass it the parameter 'vtXX' (see X -help) , where XX is the desired terminal number. There are a bunch of ways to pass parameters to X, but that is stuff for another question. :)

Answer (score 2):

F7 is the default Xserver console.
I believe that F8 is only used if there is already an Xserver running on F7, or if F7 is busy.

Comment: To add to this, if you sign out and back in (and a new X session is started), your display will then be on F8.

Answer (score 0):

Some display managers, including `lightdm`, spawn Xorg server with the `vt7` argument, that explicitly requests it to attach to tty7.