# Does the shortcut Ctrl-Alt-F... turn off the GUI or is it still running in the background?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gui

I am new to Linux and am planning on setting up a server.

What I want to know is, when I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> command to go back to the terminal does the GUI turn off until I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> again or does it just sit in the background like if you used <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows OS to switch between windows?

The reason I ask is as I am still learning I still need a GUI on hand until I get more used to terminal.

I know there are commands to stop and start LightDM but I was just curious what the keyboard shortcuts mentioned above do to the GUI when switching between them.

Answer (score 77):

When you switch to a "virtual terminal" by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> everything else remains as it was. So when you later press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or repeatedly <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>) you get back to the GUI session and can continue your work.

---

In previous Ubuntu versions *VT1* would be unused and the standard X session would run on *VT7*. Currently (at least from 18.04 onwards) *VT1* is used for the display manager ("login screen"), the standard X session uses *VT2*. Hence we have *VT3* as the first usable VT.

Comment: How do we know which combo returns as? My pc worked with alt+right button

Answer (score 8):

If you ever logged in with two users on the same machine or started gui on another tty1 with `startx`, you'd notice something like this:

```
$ who                                                                          
xieerqi  tty1         2015-07-31 22:17
xieerqi  :0           2015-07-31 22:18 (:0)
xieerqi  pts/7        2015-07-31 22:18 (:0)
```

Here I have 3 logins - on tty1, on screen :0, and in gnome-terminal. With another user, it'd be reporting another display :1. So what's happening ? All the sessions are still active, GUI and tty are active at the same time. But *switching between them makes linux switch who has control over keyboard (or more technically `stdin` device ) and screen (`stdout`) at the moment.*

Now, if I'd kill all my GUI sessions (`sudo pkill unity`), *then* GUI would be disabled temporarily. Or if I stopped `lightdm` because it's a parent process of GUI (because I logged in there). And of course it could be restarted.

GUI is not disabled, in other-words, it just doesn't have control over keyboard and screen until you switch back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> or cycle through with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L/R Arrow</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a desktop terminal, the following hotkey combination works.

```
Ctrl + Alt + d
```

A great desktop terminal is [Deskterm](https://github.com/jamrizzi/deskterm).