# Login screen goes black on 15.10

Tags: nvidia, video, screen, 15.10

First I just want to say I consider myself a beginner using Ubuntu.  I've read through most of the forums I could find which were related to this my problem and couldn't find a method which works.

Here's what happens.  When I hear the login screen sound, I see nothing but black. If I type my password to login and I hear the sound associated with logging in but the screen still stays black. If I close my laptop screen to go into sleep mode and then open it back up, the login screen is visible but then goes black after I login. I tried recovery mode and repairing packages but didn't work. I tried no splash and nomodeset but the screen just froze. Ran a system diagnostic and it gave this error message:[image]

for my video drive. I think the issue might have to do with the nVidia drivers I switched to before.  Is there a way to fix this? Thx in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

i had a similar issue when i installed ubuntu as a virtual machine.
I was able to get the gui screen using Ctrl-F7.
Ctrl key was the right side ctrl key.
You can try this combination of Ctrl-Alt-F7.
something similar to this [Switching Between GUI and Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292069/switching-between-gui-and-terminal)

Comment: Thx. I tried your key combination but nothing happened :(

Comment: @CapR You're already on Ctrl+Alt+F7. Try using for example Ctrl+Alt+F6 and you can switch between the 6 terminals, F5, F4, F3, F2, and the one that ubuntu also uses for booting, F1. In all of the terminals, Ctrl+Alt+F7 will get you back to the graphical interface.

Comment: @CapR then i think you need to uninstall your nvidia drivers and reinstall the correct version as this [http://askubuntu.com/questions/691946/how-to-solve-black-screen-problem-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-15-1?rq=1]  talks about