# Lubuntu 18.04: How to boot into terminal?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, startup

I have a machine that runs a script on startup that runs an application, and then shuts off. Occasionally, if the permissions aren't set correctly or the file path is misconfigured, this results in the machine booting up, failing, and shutting down.

In the past, I have been able to access a terminal on startup where I can enter user login and modify the files and permissions.

What shortcut allows me to open this terminal? I thought it was F3 but that isn't working.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode This? Sry, I know nothing of Lubuntu :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching Between GUI and Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292069/switching-between-gui-and-terminal)