# Session started with startx disappears after switching virtual console

Tags: xubuntu, xorg

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. I switched to another virtual console using Ctrl + Alt + F4 there is logged in and typed

```
startx
```

A UI session starts fine, then I go my original session using Ctrl + Alt + F7 switches fine, when I come back to the virtual console 4 I see only console with messages and no longer shows the UI session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is on the next console up from the default graphical session

Do:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

> If several sessions of the X Window System are required to run in parallel, such as in the case of fast user switching or when debugging X programs on a separate X server, each X session usually runs in a separate virtual console.

Basically so you can see what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: yes I can see that, why does it not start in the same virtual console ?

Comment: What I meant was if I type startx in console 4, why UI starts in console 8 and not in 4

Comment: it is started in 4 but that is just the text, do ctrl + C and it will kill it in 4, 1-6 are just virtual consoles

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5728/what-determines-which-virtual-console-the-graphical-interface-is-run-on?rq=1